# for each element of 2d array sum higher elements in the row and column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

My input dataframe (or 2D numpy array) shape is 11kx12k

For each element, I check how many values are higher in the given row and column.

For example:

```
array([[1, 3, 1, 5, 3],
       [3, 7, 3, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 1, 8, 9]])
```

row-wise:

```
3   1   3   0   1
1   0   1   3   4
3   2   4   1   0
```

column-wise:

```
2   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   2   2
1   1   1   0   0
```

total higher values for that element:

```
5   2   4   1   2
1   0   1   5   6
4   3   5   1   0
```

this code works good but for this shape of matrix It takes ~1 hour.

```
dfT = df.T
rows = df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(df>x),axis=1)
cols = dfT.apply(lambda x: np.sum(dfT>x),axis=1).T
output = rows+cols
```

I wonder is there any way to do this more efficient way?

I also tried numpy but for this I have splited my 2D to 12kx100 or 12kx200 shapes and merged all arrays again, in the end runtime was close to eachother so couldn't get any progress.

```
np.sum(matrix > matrix[:,None], axis=1)
```

Comment: Are your values all integers? Are they all below a certain amount? I'm thinking if it may help to reduce the memory requirement by using a smaller datatype. From a quick calculation, 11K by 12K of (64 bit) integers requires about 1 GB to just store the matrix. Not impossible, but it may slow things down a bit.

Comment: @9769953 they are correlation scores, between -1 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the following:

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata

def element_wise_bigger_than(x, axis):
    return x.shape[axis] - rankdata(x, method='max', axis=axis)
```

What you want is similar to a ranking of elements, which basically tells you how many items are smaller than a given element (maybe with subtracting 1 if your ranking is `1, 2, 3, ...`).  [`rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) does this ranking, and can do it row-wise or column-wise.  We can convert the "smaller than" to "bigger than" by inverting the ranks, relative to the number of items being counted (in each row/column).  I.e., subtract the ranks from the number of rows/columns.

For rows/columns without ties (e.g., the third row in your example), this works as expected.  There is a slight complication with ties and how they are ranked.  Through trial and error, I found that using `method='max'` gave the desired behavior.  To be frank, I am still wrapping my head on why/how this works, so take the answer with a grain of salt.

Still, it gives the desired output on the input data:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 3, 1, 5, 3], [3, 7, 3, 2, 1], [2, 3, 1, 8, 9]])
>>> element_wise_bigger_than(x, 1)
array([[3, 1, 3, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 3, 4],
       [3, 2, 4, 1, 0]])

>>> element_wise_bigger_than(x, 0)
array([[2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

And it can handle your size of data in far less than an hour:

```
def experiment():
    x = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(11000, 12000))
    rows = element_wise_bigger_than(x, 1)
    cols = element_wise_bigger_than(x, 0)
    output = rows + cols
    return output

%%time
experiment()
# CPU times: user 8.68 s, sys: 805 ms, total: 9.49 s
# Wall time: 9.47 s
```

**Takes about 10 seconds.**  My understanding is the ranking should be similar to a sorting operation.  My answer is relying on a scipy/numpy implementation of the rank/sort, rather than a user-written loop/"apply" (which tend to be much slower).

Comment: You posted when I was about to copy my solution, I had almost the same approach ;)

Comment: @mozway Just the other day you beat me! and probably hundreds of other times xD

Comment: @Tom thanks for answer, It works like a charm. I wanted to add another step to your solution which is if the cell is negative I want to add that value 0.05, if it is positive I want to subtract 0.05 then start counting. I edited x in rankdata function but apparently it is a vector, couldn't make it.

Comment: @tyasird glad it worked!  I'm not sure I follow your follow-up question - you want to add 0.05 to all the negative values, and subtract 0.05 from all the positive values?  And then apply the solution as normal?  Sounds like a use of [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).  You might need to post a new question

Comment: No, instead of adding or subtracting to all values, I would like to add 0.05 just to the cell where the calculation is made. lambda version would be like `df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(df > x+0.05 if x<0 else x-0.05), axis=1)`. But you're right it is better to post new question might be more clear. Thank you again, saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, where `a` is the initial array, which uses row-wise `numpy broadcasting`:

```
def get_horizontal(a):
    z = np.array([(x > y).sum() for x in a[:, None] 
                  for y in x.flatten() ]).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
    return z

get_horizontal(a) + get_horizontal(a.T).T
```

---

The previous solution takes a long time to run. Thus, to speed up the calculations, we can use `numba` and [`numba prange`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html?highlight=prange#explicit-parallel-loops) to parallelize the `for` loop:

```
from numba import jit, prange, njit, set_num_threads
import numpy as np

@njit(parallel=True)
def get_horizontal(a):
    z = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]), dtype=np.int32)
    for i in prange(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            z[i, j] = (a[i, j] < a[i, :]).sum()
    return z

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(11000, 12000))

set_num_threads(6) # to use only 6 threads

# to get the transposed array as a contiguous array
b = np.ascontiguousarray(a.T) 

get_horizontal(a) + get_horizontal(b).T
```

This code took about 1 minute and 30 seconds to run.

---

Output:

```
array([[5, 2, 4, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 1, 5, 6],
       [4, 3, 5, 1, 0]])

# row_wise
array([[3, 1, 3, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 3, 4],
       [3, 2, 4, 1, 0]])

# column_wise
array([[2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I liked the approach, however when I try the code, for me It doesn't take 1second, It is around 10 minutes now and still running. Would it be possible you to check it again? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @tyasird, for your comment. I did a mistake: In `rows = get_horizontal(a)` I should have put `x` instead of `a`. Consequently, the reported timing was for your small array. I am going to correct my answer.

Comment: I have just added a solution that uses `numba`, @tyasird. Its runtime, when using 6 threads, is about 10 minutes on my computer.

Comment: thank you for the answer, since I do have a normalization step before counting the values, I guess this approach is more useful for me. I will try it now, I explained my normalization step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77422410/manipulate-the-element-before-finding-sum-of-higher-elements-in-the-row).

Comment: Just posted a solution for your follow up question, @tyasird.