# manipulate the element before finding sum of higher elements in the row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have asked about finding sum of higher elements in the row/column and got really good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77418144/for-each-element-of-2d-array-sum-higher-elements-in-the-row-and-column).
However this approach does not allow me to manipulate current element.

My input dataframe is something like this:

```
array([[-1,  7, -2,  1,  4],
       [ 6,  3,  -3,  5,  1]])
```

Basically, I would like to have a output matrix which shows me for each element how many values are higher in the given row and column, like this:

```
array([[3, 0, 4, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 4, 1, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

`scipy ranked` function really works well here.  (Thanks to @[Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13386979/tom))

the tricky part is here since this matrix is correlation matrix and scores are between -1 and 1,
**I would like to add one middle step (normalization factor) before counting higher values:**

If the element is negative, add +3 to that element and then count how many values are higher
If the element is positive, subtract -3 from that element and then count how many values are higher in the row.

e.g.:

first element of row is negative we add +3 and then row would be
`2 7 -2 1 4` ->  sum of the higher values from that element is 2
second element of row is positive we subtract -3 and then row would be
`-1 4 -2 1 4` -> sum of the higher values from that element is 0

...

so we do this normalization for each row and row-wise desired output would be:

```
2 0 2 3 1 
1 3 4 2 3
```

I don't want to use loop for that because since the matrix is `11kx12k`, it takes so much time.
If I use `ranked` with `lamda`, than instead of doing for each element, It adds and subtracts in the same time to the all row values, which It is not what I want.

```
corr = np.array([[-1,  7, -2,  1,  4],
                 [ 6,  3,  -3,  5,  1]])


def element_wise_bigger_than(x, axis):
    return x.shape[axis] - rankdata(x, method='max', axis=axis)


ld = lambda t: t + 3 if t<0 else t-3
f = np.vectorize(ld)


element_wise_bigger_than(f(corr), 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `numba` and [`numba prange`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html?highlight=prange#explicit-parallel-loops) to parallelize the `for` loop:

```
from numba import jit, prange, njit, set_num_threads
import numpy as np

@njit(parallel=True)
def get_horizontal(a):
    z = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]), dtype=np.int32)
    
    for i in prange(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            aux = a[i, j]
            
            if a[i, j] < 0:
                a[i, j] += 3
            elif a[i, j] > 0:
                a[i, j] -= 3
            else:
                pass
            
            z[i, j] = (a[i, j] < a[i, :]).sum()
            a[i, j] = aux
    return z

a = np.array([[-1,  7, -2,  1,  4],
       [ 6,  3,  -3,  5,  1]])

set_num_threads(6) # to use only 6 threads

get_horizontal(a)
```

---

Runtime:

By using the following array,

```
a = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=(11000, 12000))
```

the runtime, on my computer, is less than 1 minute.

---

Output:

```
array([[2, 0, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 3, 4, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: hey Paul, thanks for the solution! yes I think I made a mistake with the output, I edited it now, and will run the code and lets see about runtime.

Comment: I've just tried the code, run time is ~45 second for `a` array, but when I want to do same operation for `column-wise`, I just gave `a.T` as an input to `get_horizontal` function, It's been 15 minutes and still running. Do you have any idea what is the reason for this?

Comment: I am not sure, but I suspect that `a.T` is not contiguous in memory as it is `a`, @tyasird. That makes numba's cache rather inefficient! Try: `b` instead of `a.T`, where `b = np.ascontiguousarray(a.T)`. On my side, with this trick, the runtime is about 40 seconds.